# AppRoleAssignments Errors With Null

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I am trying to add and and AppRoleAssignment using ActiveDirectoryClient.  I am able to add the user with no issues to the Azure AD, but when trying to add the Application I receive the the following:

> A null value was found for the property named 'id', which has the expected type 'Edm.Guid[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'Edm.Guid[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.

I am using the following:

```
var servicePrincipal = (await
            activeDirectoryClient.ServicePrincipals.Where(
                s => s.DisplayName == "Tracker.Web").ExecuteAsync()).CurrentPage
            .First();

        var appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment
        {
            Id = Guid.Empty,
            ResourceDisplayName = "Tracker.Web",
            // Service principal id go here
            ResourceId = Guid.Parse(servicePrincipal.ObjectId),
            PrincipalType = "User",
            PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(newUser.ObjectId)
        };




        newUser.AppRoleAssignments.Add(appRoleAssignment);

        await newUser.UpdateAsync();
```

I have also tried various other iterations of this with and received the same results.  I found this:

[Try to adding AppRoleAssignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38075294/try-to-adding-approleassignment)

But is over 2 years old.  Is this still an issue after 2 years or am I doing something wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, you could mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> The expected type 'Edm.Guid[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values

According to the error information, it indicates that the null value is not allow for Id. We could generate Guid for the AppRoleAssignment Id.

please change  `Id = Guid.Empty` to  `Id = Guid.NewGuid()`

Demo code:

```
var appRoleAssignment = new AppRoleAssignment
    {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(), //null value for Id is not allowed
            ResourceDisplayName = "Tracker.Web",
            // Service principal id go here
            ResourceId = Guid.Parse(servicePrincipal.ObjectId),
            PrincipalType = "User",
            PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(newUser.ObjectId)
     };
```

For more demo code, you refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52011625/issue-with-remove-application-role-in-azuread-using-graphapi-c-sharp/52035691#52035691).